# On splitting Scala list, clarification needed

Tags: list, scala

Given

```
println(split(7, (1 to 15).toList))
```

When running

```
  def split[X](n: Int, xs: List[X]): (List[X], List[X]) = {
    if (n <= 0) (Nil, xs)
    else if (n >= xs.size) (xs, Nil)
    else {
      val grouped = xs.grouped(n).toList
      return (grouped(0), grouped(1))
    }
  }
```

I get

```
(List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7),List(8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14))
```

Why is the last element dropped please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`grouped` returns three `IndexedSeq` and you are only returning the first two.

```
scala> (1 to 15).grouped(7).toList
res0: List[scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int]] = List(
  Vector(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7), 
  Vector(8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14),
  Vector(15)
)
```

`grouped` returns *An iterator producing lists of size size, except the last will be truncated if the elements don't divide evenly* so you can see where grouping 15 items with 7 returns an extra `List`.

Answer (score 2):

Because you get three lists.

You partition your list of 15 elements into lists of (up to) 7 elements each. You end up with a list of 7, a second one of 7 and a third of 1 element.